# How to reuse spark RDD after stopping the Context

Tags: java, apache-spark, rdd

I have created an RDD, Below is my Program.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException, IOException, InterruptedException {

         SparkConf conf1 = new SparkConf().setAppName("SparkAutomation").setMaster("local");

         app.run(conf1);

}


private void run(SparkConf conf) throws JSONException, IOException,    InterruptedException {
JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);

getDataFrom(sc);
sc.stop();   

}

 void getDataFrom(JavaSparkContext sc) throws JSONException, IOException, InterruptedException {

JavaRDD<String> Data = sc.textFile("/path/to/File");

}
```

I want to use the RDD created above in the other part of the application , I have to stop the context , I need to create another Context , and will use the above RDD there. My question is will I be able to use the RDD if I persist that to Memory ?

```
  Data.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY());
```

Or do I have to persist that to Disk.

```
  Data.persist(StorageLevel.DISK_ONLY());
```

Answer (score 5):

You won't be able to reuse that RDD in either situation if you need to restart your Spark Context. Things persisted with `RDD.persist` are not accessible outside of your Spark Context. Each RDD is specifically tied to an individual Spark Context.

If you want to stop the context and start a new one consider persisting to an underlying datastore using something like `RDD.saveAsTextFile("/saved/rdd/path")` and then reading a new RDD in the new Spark Context using `sc.textFile("/saved/rdd/path")`.